# How can I obtain the current date containing also the second's cent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am not so into JavaScript.

How can I retrieve the current datetime with these information: year, month, day, hour, minute, second, cent of second?

What is the smarted way to do it?

Comment: What exactly is cent of second? [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) gives you the current datetime down to milliseconds in Javascript

Comment: `cent of second` is actually `milisecond`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from `new Date()` and play with different methods, like this:

```
var d = new Date(); 
d.getFullYear();    
d.getMonth();       
d.getDay();         
d.getHours();       
d.getMinutes();     
d.getSeconds();   
d.getMilliseconds();
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is using Date:

```
var date = new Date();
```

That will give you the current date and time. You can use Moment.JS as well:

```
var date = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');;
```